# What is the difference between DBN and D/CTMC in terms of model representation and parameters estimation?

Tags: references, modeling, markov-process, bayesian-network

After researching about Dynamic Bayesian Network (DBN) and Discrete/Continuous Time Markov Chain (D/CTMC), I found them to be very similar, but I am sure there are some differences between them. I am not sure which one I should use to model a reduced complex system.

From what I have been told/ known so far, in terms of model representations, DBN can be reduced to D/CTMC. Both have the disadvantages of state explosion if used in modeling a very complex system.

So, what is the difference between DBN and D/CTMC in terms of model representation and parameters estimation? What is the advantages of DBN over D/CTMC and vice-versa? Which one is more widely used? References will be much appreciated.